Random characters displayed Ubuntu 22.04.04
Running System 76 Onyx Pro running Ubuntu 22.04.04 LTS.  The issue has happened since I bought the device however tech support was never really able to help me.  It has been a year and I am finally trying to figure out the issue myself.
I have some experience with Linux as a user but a complete novice related to anything OS related.  So not even sure how much of what is below is related or completely unrelated.
When I close the lid and use an external keyboard and mouse I get random mouse movement and random characters appearing.  When I open the lid the issue completely goes away, even with external mouse and keyboard attached.
Looking at: /var/log/syslog there are many messages of an input device disconnecting and reconnecting.  Like every second or so.
Aug 28 22:05:03 system76-pc acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 30  
Aug 28 22:05:04 system76-pc kernel: [975977.344107] input: AT Raw Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5391993  
Aug 28 22:05:05 system76-pc acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 30  
Aug 28 22:05:05 system76-pc kernel: [975978.009775] input: AT Raw Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5391994  
Aug 28 22:05:05 system76-pc acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 30  
Aug 28 22:05:06 system76-pc kernel: [975979.359985] input: AT Raw Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5392006  

Looking at libinput list-devices:
Device:           AT Translated Set 2 keyboard  
Kernel:           /dev/input/event4  
Group:            11 /  
Seat:             seat0, default  
Capabilities:     keyboard  

cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab83
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event4 leds [
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 c3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

Checking the folder: /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4 there are subfolders for
input4::capslock
input4::numlock
input4::scrolllock
power
Looking at  journalctl -b There are constant error messages as below.
Aug 20 09:14:46 system76-pc gnome-shell[2650]: Could not open device /dev/input/event30: Could not get device info for p>  
Aug 20 09:16:02 system76-pc gnome-shell[2650]: Could not open device /dev/input/event30: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBu>  
Aug 20 09:17:40 system76-pc gnome-shell[2650]: Could not open device /dev/input/event30: Could not get device info for p>  
Aug 20 09:18:00 system76-pc gnome-shell[2650]: Could not open device /dev/input/event30: Could not get device info for p>  

But I can clearly show that the input30 does exist in the sys/class path.  It does not exist in the /dev path but I am not sure it is supposed to.
system76-pc:/sys/class/input/input30$ cat name
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9
Any idea if the AT Translated Set 2 being disconnected can be related to my random characters?  Is there a clean way to disable AT Translated Set 2 keyboard such that if anything stops working I can re-enable it easily and not end up bricking the system?
is it feasible that Could not open device /dev/input/event30 is related?
Any recommendations for where to search for answers would be greatly appreciated.
I have followed a few various suggestions on websites related related to stuttering and timing but none of them solved my issue.  None of them where really a direct match for the issue I am seeing.  Just more tried out of desperation. For example:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbhid.kbpoll=1 usbhid.mousepoll=1"
In an effort to debug this I created a program to log event activity. If I press a key on a keyboard it successfully captures the activity.  It is also capturing mouse events.
ret 1  
received data on device 4  
Event: time 140732299790624.126920578564096, type 3432 (?), code 0 (?), value 0  
Event: time 140732299789344.140728898420736, type 48 (?), code 0 (?), value 0  
Event: time 0.000000, type 10 (?), code 0 (?), value 29551  
^[[18~^[[18~^C  

I am monitoring all /dev/input/event files.  So I don't understand what else can trigger an event.
Another example with the random characters showing: ^[[18~
/dev/input/event0:  Power Button  
/dev/input/event1:  Sleep Button  
/dev/input/event2:  Lid Switch  
/dev/input/event3:  Power Button  
/dev/input/event4:  AT Translated Set 2 keyboard  
/dev/input/event5:  System76 ACPI Hotkeys  
/dev/input/event6:  FTCS1000:00 2808:0102 Mouse  
/dev/input/event7:  FTCS1000:00 2808:0102 Touchpad  
/dev/input/event8:  MOSART Semi. 2.4G INPUT DEVICE  
/dev/input/event9:  MOSART Semi. 2.4G INPUT DEVICE Mouse  
/dev/input/event10: MOSART Semi. 2.4G INPUT DEVICE Consumer Control  
/dev/input/event11: MOSART Semi. 2.4G INPUT DEVICE System Control  
/dev/input/event12: MOSART Semi. 2.4G INPUT DEVICE  
/dev/input/event13: Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia   Keyboard  
/dev/input/event14: Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard System Control  
/dev/input/event15: Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard Consumer Control  
/dev/input/event16: Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard  
Removing Intel PCH and NVIDIA HDMI DEV for brevity

ret 3  
received data on device 4  
Event: time 140728371063632.000000, type 3432 (?), code 0 (?), value 0  
Event: time 129337380664352.129334350184448, type 10032 (?), code 57489 (?), value 0  
Event: time 140724603453440.000000, type 10 (?), code 0 (?), value 30113  
received data on device 8  
Event: time 140728371063632.000000, type 3432 (?), code 0 (?), value 0  
Event: time 129337380664352.129334350184448, type 10032 (?), code 57489 (?), value 0  
Event: time 140724603453440.000000, type 10 (?), code 0 (?), value 30113  
received data on device 13  
Event: time 140728371063632.000000, type 3432 (?), code 0 (?), value 0  
Event: time 129337380664352.129334350184448, type 10032 (?), code 57489 (?), value 0  
Event: time 140724603453440.000000, type 10 (?), code 0 (?), value 30113  
^[[18~  
ret 3  
received data on device 4  
Event: time 140728371063632.000000, type 3432 (?), code 0 (?), value 0  
Event: time 129337380664352.129334350184448, type 10032 (?), code 57489 (?), value 0  
Event: time 140724603453440.000000, type 10 (?), code 0 (?), value 30113  
received data on device 8  
Event: time 140728371063632.000000, type 3432 (?), code 0 (?), value 0  
Event: time 129337380664352.129334350184448, type 10032 (?), code 57489 (?), value 0  
Event: time 140724603453440.000000, type 10 (?), code 0 (?), value 30113  
received data on device 13  
Event: time 140728371063632.000000, type 3432 (?), code 0 (?), value 0  
Event: time 129337380664352.129334350184448, type 10032 (?), code 57489 (?), value 0  
Event: time 140724603453440.000000, type 10 (?), code 0 (?), value 30113  

But when I do actual keypresses (a,b,and c below) the keypress is visible but it still doesn't capture it in the keypress logger.  So the keypresses are not getting recorded:
a  
ret 1  
received data on device 13  
Event: time 140735666597264.000000, type 3432 (?), code 0 (?), value 0  
Event: time 123237977650208.123235496624128, type 10608 (?), code 37738 (?), value 0  
Event: time 140733193388032.000000, type 10 (?), code 0 (?), value 28693  
  
ret 1  
received data on device 13  
Event: time 140735666597264.000000, type 3432 (?), code 0 (?), value 0  
Event: time 123237977650208.123235496624128, type 10608 (?), code 37738 (?), value 0  
Event: time 140733193388032.000000, type 10 (?), code 0 (?), value 28693  
b  
ret 1  
received data on device 13  
Event: time 140735666597264.000000, type 3432 (?), code 0 (?), value 0  
Event: time 123237977650208.123235496624128, type 10608 (?), code 37738 (?), value 0  
Event: time 140733193388032.000000, type 10 (?), code 0 (?), value 28693  
  
ret 1  
received data on device 13  
Event: time 140735666597264.000000, type 3432 (?), code 0 (?), value 0  
Event: time 123237977650208.123235496624128, type 10608 (?), code 37738 (?), value 0  
Event: time 140733193388032.000000, type 10 (?), code 0 (?), value 28693  
c  
ret 1  
received data on device 13  
Event: time 140735666597264.000000, type 3432 (?), code 0 (?), value 0  
Event: time 123237977650208.123235496624128, type 10608 (?), code 37738 (?), value 0  
Event: time 140733193388032.000000, type 10 (?), code 0 (?), value 28693  


Looks like I can ignore the one error message:
'Aug 20 09:58:43 system76-pc gnome-shell[2650]: Could not open device /dev/input/event30: Could not get device info for path /dev/input/event30: No such file or direct>  '  Based on this article: link

Following https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381944/how-to-disable-internal-keyboard-on-fedora-26-wayland/702857#702857 I tried disabling the keypad and it did not solve the random key presses.

Further in my debug I used sudo evtest and specified multiple event numbers hoping to see when random characters occured, which event fired. but so far after trying Lid Switch, Power Button, AT Translated Set 2 Keyboard, and System 76 ACPI Hotkeys, non of them have worked yet.  Unfortunately evtest only lets you do one at a time. I am researching using either Logging https://github.com/kernc/logkeys or UDEV rules to try to monitor all the events at the same time.
